# How to use gfx in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, gfx

I have a pygame game and I want to use pygame.gfxdraw.aacricle(), but whenever I do it gives me an error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'gfxdraw'

How do I install gfx for python 2.7?

Comment: Do you have pygame 1.9+ installed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had this same issue using gfxdraw in pygame as well. Once I imported the module explicitly, there were no issues. Adding this line after importing pygame fixed the issue:

```
import pygame.gfxdraw
```

Curiously, I don't need to import pygame.draw explicitly in order to use it.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I had to do to fix the application I was developing (Python 2.7, latest pygame, Ubuntu x64).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [compilation and installation guide](http://www.swftools.org/gfx_tutorial.html) for gfx.

For the basic install it's the standard:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Or did you already try this and run into some problems?

Comment: I went to that website and downloaded the file they suggested: http://www.swftools.org/download.html . It was an exe, so I ran it and gfx still isn't installed. I have no idea what the instruction means.

Comment: @lemiant did you get any sort of error/warning messages during the installation?

Comment: No it went through clean. It just didn't have any obvious effects.

Comment: In fact the download linked there isn't even a compressed file

Comment: @lemiant it's not that unusual for install packages to be in .exe format. I am assuming you've tried to reinstall this? Is it possible you've run into some permission problems (though I would expect some error/warning messages in that case) i.e., did you have to install this as administrator? Is there a pygame forum you could post your query? Did you download this version? http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Installation#How_do_I_install_swftools_on_Windows.3F

Comment: I don't believe this is `pygame.gfxdraw` , but `gfx`. I just tested my pygame, and `import pygame.gfxdraw` worked. I don't believe I did a second install, just pygame-1.9.2-pre.

Comment: Monkey, you got it, thanks! I would have expected "import pygame" to import everything, but apparently it doesn't. You should make that an answer